# How do I find the mode of an array of integers in C++ using an array to hold the counters?

Tags: c++11

I need to find the mode of an array and my professor told us to use another array to hold the repetitions of each number. Here's my mode function:

```
int mode(int *arr, int s)
{
int num = arr[0];
int mod = num;
int modeCount[s];
int countMode = 1;

for(int count = 1; count < s; count++)
{
    if(arr[count] == num)
        modeCount[count - 1]++;
    else
    {
        if(modeCount[count] > countMode)
        {
            countMode = modeCount[count - 1];
            mod = num;
        }
    }
    num = arr[count];


}

return mod;

}
```

And using an array such as {1, 5, 3, 5} my mode comes out to being 3.

I should also mention that I don't have to code different if there are multiple modes(professor said don't worry about it) and I must return -1 if there is no mode, so this code is incomplete.

Anyone got any ideas on how to fix my code and make it work?

Comment: Professor advised you to use an array, or you must use an array?

Comment: She advised but basically hinted that we should use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the elements of the array are limited by s, you can use this idea.

```
int mode(int* arr, int s)
{
    int count[s + 1] = {0}; // The size is s + 1, in case the elements on the array belong to the interval [0, S]

    for(int i = 0; i < s; ++i)
        count[arr[i]]++;

    int best = 0;
    int mode = -1;
    int numberOfElementsTied = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < s; ++i)
    {
        if( count[i] > best)
        {
            best = count[i];
            mode = i;
            numberOfElementsTied = 1;
        }
        else if( count[i] == best)
        {
            numberOfElementsTied++;
        }
    }

    if(numberOfElementsTied == 1) return mode;
    else return -1;
}
```

Comment: Seems to work when there is a mode, however, if I use an array with no mode, such as {1, 2, 3, 4}, the number returned is still 1. I tried troubleshooting by using a method similar to finding the largest number in an array, but it still didn't work. And can you explain why the count array's size had to be increased by 1?

Comment: I am assuming that the values belong to the range [1, s]. So it was necessary to create the count array with size s+1, so that the elements there can go from [0, s].